# No releases available for package "pear.php.net/File_IMC"

Tags: php, pear

i try to install pear extension, the command looks like this:
pear install File_IMC

but i get a error
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/File_IMC"

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using PEAR2 instead like described on http://pear.php.net/package/File_IMC - it is used like this:

```
php pyrus.phar install pear/File_IMC
```